# Ошибка при использовании шаблонизатора Twig на другом компьютере

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы, twig

Работал и работает на одном сервере нормально шаблонизатор Twig. Решил перенести на другой компьютер. Выдаёт ошибку:

> *An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Class "Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Equal" not found in "C:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\testlocal\application/Core/Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Equal.php" and in "C:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\testlocal\application/Twig/Twig_Node_Expression_Binary_Equal.php"") in "/Templates/MainTemplate_view.html".#0 C:\OpenServer\OpenServer\domains\testlocal\lib\Twig\Environment.php(334): Twig_Environment->compileSource('*

Сам код шаблона:

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="Menu" ><a ng-class="{'bold': window.location.pathname == '/trainings'}" ng-href="/trainings">Тренировка</a></li>
        <li class="Menu" ng-class="{'bold': window.location.pathname == '/exam'}"><a ng-href="/exam">Экзамен</a></li>
        {% if role=='1' %} <li class="Menu"><a ng-href="/admin" ng-class="{'bold': location.pathname == '/admin'}">Панель администратора</a></li>{% endif %}
        <li class="Menu" ng-class="{'bold': window.location.pathname == '/settings'}"><a ng-href="/settings">Настройки</a></li>
        <li class="Menu" ng-class="{'bold': window.location.pathname == '/description'}"><a ng-href="/description">Описание</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><p>{% if role=='1' %}<span class="label label-warning">Администратор</span>{% endif %} ФИО: {{Session_Fio}} -<a href="/logout" id="logout_button" onclick="window.location = '/logout'"> Выход </a></p></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Этот код его вызывает:

```
function action_mainview()
{   
    $role = $_SESSION['role'];
    echo $this->view->render('/Templates/MainTemplate_view.html', array('role' => $role,'login'=> $_SESSION['User'])); 
}
```

Дело в том, что если убрать `if /endif`, то всё работает. Как такое можно объяснить, что на одном компьютере это работает, а на другом точная копия - не работает?

Comment: Вероятнее всего, отсутствует часть файлов  Twig.

Comment: Да. Действительно. Скачал с более старой версии- там отличались файлы